# Awesome table function

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms, javascript

Is there an option in awesome-table.com with the edit links such that the result of the form will be to create a new line in the spreadsheet and only alter the values instead of editing the existing?

My idea is a history to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function doing that. But I solved my problem through Google Forms and google script. I got a prerpopulated link from the Google Forms menu and created a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108511/is-it-possible-to-prefill-a-google-form-using-data-from-a-google-spreadsheet/20110656#20110656) to prepopulate the form with the data from the rows and write the links in a column for each row replacing the edit link suggested in awesome-table.